# Finding closest value in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary, `T`, with keys in the form `k,i` with an associated value that is a real number (float). Let's suppose I choose a particular key `a,b` from the dictionary `T` with corresponding value `V1`—what's the most efficient way to find the closest value to `V1` for a key that has the form `a+1,i`, where `i` is an integer that ranges from 0 to n? (`k`,`a`, and `b` are also integers.) To add one condition on the values of items in `T`, as `i` increases in the key, the value associated to `T[a+1,i]` is strictly increasing (i.e. `T[a+1,i+1] > T[a+1,i]`).

I was planning to simply run a while loop that starts from `i = 0` and compares the value`T[a+1,i]` to `V1`. To be more clear, the loop would simply stop at the point at which `np.abs(T[a+1,i] - V1) < np.abs(T[a+1,i+1] - V1)`, as I would know the item associated to `T[a+1,i]` is the closest to `T[a,b] = V1`. But given the strictly increasing condition I have imposed, is there a more efficient method than running a while loop that iterates over the dictionary elements? `i` will go from 0 to n where n could be an integer in the millions. Also, this process would be repeated frequently so efficiency is key.

Comment: *keys in the form k,i*, does it mean that dictionary is a sort of 2-D array?

Comment: @Jeon Yes, it is similar to a 2D array (e.g. increasing time as i increases). A dictionary was chosen to allow for nonuniform spacing. Although one of the (minor) problems is figuring out how things are arranged simply based on keys.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri This isn't an assignment... It's a personal project with a nonuniform grid. I would like to find a good method to compute the spatial derivatives. I am trying to find the closest value to my current point (e.g. `V1`) to compute the numerical differential. I have not implemented a particular method yet since it's to be added to another code to solve a set of PDEs. Although before changing my code (only to change it again in the end if I learn of better methods), I thought I would ask ahead of time if more efficient techniques exist that I am simply unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

Since the values for a given `a` are strictly increasing with successive `i` values, you can do a binary search for the value that is closest to your target.

While it's certainly possible to write your own binary search code on your dictionary, I suspect you'd have an easier time with a different data structure. If you used nested lists (with `a` as the index to the outer list, and `i` as the index to an inner list), you could use the `bisect` module to search the inner list efficiently.

Comment: Using a dictionary is a constraint for other purposes in the code, so another data structure is unfortunately not an option. I'll look into existing binary search codes out there. Thank you for the suggestions. I did find code such as 

`idx1 = np.array(T.keys())`

`vals1 = np.array(T.values())`

`dims1 = idx1.max(0)+1`

`out1 = np.zeros(dims1,dtype=vals1.dtype)`

`out1[idx1[:,0],idx1[:,1]] = vals1` 

which could help, but converting the dict into an array for every single time may be even more inefficient, as once again the dict is nonuniform and updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

target_value = 0.9 
dict = {(1, 2): 0, (4, 3): 1}

k = list(dict.keys())
v = np.array(list(dict.values()))
dist = abs(v - target_value)
arg = np.argmin(dist)
answer = k[arg]

print(answer)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. As I commented above on another answer, making an array for every instance I want to do this will be inefficient as the whole point of using a dict is because the grid is nonuniform and constantly being updated. So the array made here would have to be done every single instance I do the comparison (which could also be in the millions) as the dict will be updated, and I suspect this will be quite inefficient. Although I'll try it out and compare.

Comment: Including numpy is complete overkill

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use bisect module.

```
import bisect
import numpy as np


t = np.array([[1.1, 2.0, 3.7],
              [3.5, 5.6, 7.8],
              [2.5, 3.4, 10.0]])


def find_closest(t, a, i):
    """
    >>> find_closest(t, 0, 2)
    (1, 0)
    """
    v = t[a, i]
    b_index = bisect.bisect_right(t[a + 1], v)
    try:
        if t[a + 1][b_index] - v > t[a + 1][b_index - 1] - v:
            b_index -= 1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    return a + 1, b_index
```